# Como salvar uma lista de elementos com Shared Preferences

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

Estou criando uma lista de contatos e gostaria de salvar essa lista com *SharedPreferences*.

Exemplo:

```java
public class MeusContatos extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    int pos=0;
    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "Preferences";
    private List<Contatos> contatos = new ArrayList<Contatos>();
    private ContatoAdapter adaptador = null;

    EditText etNome;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_meus_contatos);

         /*
        etNome = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nome);

        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
        etNome.setText(settings.getString("PrefUsuario",""));


        Button salvar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.salvar);
        salvar.setOnClickListener(this);
        */

        ListView lista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.contato);
        adaptador = new ContatoAdapter();
        lista.setAdapter(adaptador);

    }

    protected void onStop(){
        super.onStop();

        Button salvar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.salvar);
        salvar.setOnClickListener(this);

        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        editor.putString("PrefUsuario", etNome.getText().toString());

        editor.commit();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_meus_contatos, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void onClick(View v){
        EditText nome = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nome);
        EditText email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
        EditText telefone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.telefone);

        Contatos contato = new Contatos();

        contato.setNome(nome.getText().toString());
        contato.setEmail(email.getText().toString());
        contato.setTelefone(telefone.getText().toString());

        String name  = nome.getText().toString();
        String mail = email.getText().toString();
        String fone  = telefone.getText().toString();

        RadioGroup tipoContato = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.tipo_contato);

        switch (tipoContato.getCheckedRadioButtonId()){
            case R.id.pessoal:
                contato.setTipo(Contatos.Tipo.PESSOAL);
                break;
            case R.id.profissional:
                contato.setTipo(Contatos.Tipo.PROFISSIONAL);
                break;
            case R.id.academico:
                contato.setTipo(Contatos.Tipo.ACADEMICO);
                break;
        }
        adaptador.add(contato);

    }

//CRIANDO UM ADAPTADOR PARA MELHORAR A LISTA DE ITENS
    private class ContatoAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

        public ContatoAdapter() {
            super(MeusContatos.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                    contatos);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View linha = convertView;
            ArmazenadorDeContatos armazenador = null;

            if (linha == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                linha = inflater.inflate(R.layout.elemento_lista, null);
                armazenador = new ArmazenadorDeContatos(linha);
                linha.setTag(armazenador);
            } else {
                armazenador = (ArmazenadorDeContatos) linha.getTag();
            }

            armazenador.popularFormulario(contatos.get(position));

            return linha;
        }
    }

    static class ArmazenadorDeContatos {
        private TextView nome = null;
        private TextView email = null;
        private TextView telefone = null;
        private ImageView icone = null;

        public ArmazenadorDeContatos(View linha) {
            nome = (TextView) linha.findViewById(R.id.titulo);
            email = (TextView) linha.findViewById(R.id.subtitulo);
            telefone = (TextView) linha.findViewById(R.id.subTel);

            icone = (ImageView) linha.findViewById(R.id.icone);
        }

        void popularFormulario(Contatos contato) {
            nome.setText(contato.getNome());
            email.setText(contato.getEmail());
            telefone.setText(contato.getTelefone());

            switch (contato.getTipo()) {
                case ACADEMICO:
                    icone.setImageResource(R.drawable.img_oi);
                    break;
                case PESSOAL:
                    icone.setImageResource(R.drawable.img_claro);
                    break;
                case PROFISSIONAL:
                    icone.setImageResource(R.drawable.img_vivo);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 8):

Uma alternativa para serializar em qualquer versão é criar um `JSON`, no caso um array, a partir da sua coleção de contatos, e salvar como `String` no `SharedPreferences`.

## Para serializar

Basta criar um `JSONArray`, preenche-lo com `JSONObject's` com os dados do contato e obter a `String` para salvar:

```
JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
JSONObject obj;

for(Contato c : contatos) {
   obj = new JSONObject();

   obj.put("nome", contato.getNome());
   // Adicionar as demais propriedades...

   array.put(obj);
}

String arrayStr = array.toString();

SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

editor.putString("contatos", arrayStr).commit();
```

O `JSON` que será armazenado no `SharedPreferences` no final terá essa forma:

```
[{nome: 'NOME', email: 'EMAIL', ...}, {...}, {...}, ...]
```

## Para recuperar

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);

JSONArray array = new JSONArray(sharedPreferences.getString("contatos"));
List<Contato> contatos = new ArrayList<Contato>();
Contato contato;
JSONObject obj;

for(int i = 0; i < array.length(); ++i) {
    obj = array.getJSONObject(i);

    contato = new Contato();

    contato.setNome(obj.getString("nome"));
    // O mesmo para as demais propriedades...

    contatos.add(contato);    
}
```

## OBS

Nunca é bom usar `SharedPreferences` como uma forma de armazenamento para muitos objetos. O propósito do `SharedPreferences` é guardar opções do usuário, mas nada impede de utilizar para outros meios. O mais recomendado para o requisito é usar o `SQLite`, mas tudo depende da necessidade.

Answer (score 4):

**A partir da API 11** você pode salvar os contatos usando `Set`.
Com a lista de contatos em mãos basta fazer o seguinte:

```
//Salvando
private void saveContactList(ArrayList<Contatos> listaDeContatos){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

    Set<String> contactSet = new HashSet<>();
    contactSet.addAll(listaDeContatos);

    editor.putStringSet("lista_de_contatos_key", contactSet);
    editor.commit();
}

//Recuperando
private ArrayList<Contatos> retrieveContactList(){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
    Set<String> concatcSet = sharedPreferences.getStringSet("lista_de_contatos_key", null);

    return new ArrayList<Contatos>(contactSet);
}
```

Referência: [stackoverflow.com/questions/7057845/save-arraylist-to-sharedpreferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7057845/save-arraylist-to-sharedpreferences)